# margin:0 auto; not working for the whole page

Tags: .net, css, master-pages

I have a MasterPage (in .net) and I am applying :

```
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;   
}
```

to :

```
<body>
<div id = "wrapper" >
   here goes my content
</div>
</body>
```

but it is not working ....
can you help in this matter, plz

Comment: What is not working? If you wanted it to be centred, you need to give the wrapper a width

Comment: thank you all , your solutions helped me , I have added width to it ....

Comment: @Lucky you are more than welcome for the help. Don't forget to accept an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Margin Auto only works when DIV have fixed width

```
#wrapper {
           position: relative;
           margin: 0 auto;
           width: 950px;   
          }
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to specify the div width also...

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply a width to the wrapper. For example `width:960px`

Answer (score 1):

You should set a width for that wrapper element to get margin working as expected.